# Estimating the probability density of a component of a mixture distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random variable with probability distribution $P$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be an invertible function and let $P_{f}$ be the distribution of random variable $f(X)$. Suppose $P$ and $P_f$ are such that the mixture distribution $(1-\alpha)P + \alpha P_f$, for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$, is equal to the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, I_{d\times d})$, where $I_{d\times d}$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix.

Given $\alpha, f$, I'm interested in finding the distribution $P$ for which the above condition holds, *i.e.,*  $(1-\alpha)P + \alpha P_f$ is equal to $\mathcal{N}(0, I_{d\times d})$. (By finding a distribution what I mean is that, at any given $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I would like to compute the probability density of $P$ at $x$.)

Here are my questions:

1) For any given $\alpha, f$,  is there a unique $P$ which satisfies this *i.e.,* is the problem identifiable? Or can there be multiple distributions? Of course, when $\alpha = 1/2$ the problem is clearly not identifiable. Assuming $\alpha \neq 1/2$, is the problem identifiable?

2) Assuming the problem is identifiable, how can I compute the density of $P$ at any given $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$? We have the following relation between the densities of $P, P_f$ and $\mathcal{N}(0, I_{d\times d})$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} = (1-\alpha)p(x) + \alpha |\det{J_{f^{-1}}(x)}|  p(f^{-1}(x)),$$

where $p(x)$ is the probability density of $P$ at $x$ and $\det{J_{f^{-1}}(x)}$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of $f^{-1}$ evaluated at $x$. Is there a way to compute $p(x)$ from this equation?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\x}{\bar x}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}$
Welcome to MathOverflow! 
If $\al\ne1/2$ and $f$ is an involution of $\R^d$ (so that $f=f^{-1}$), then $p$ is identifiable and can be found as follows. 
We have 
\begin{equation*}
 \phi(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} = (1-\al)p(x) + \al |\det{J_{f^{-1}}(x)}|  p(f^{-1}(x)) 
\end{equation*}
for all $x\in\R^d$, which we can rewrite as 
\begin{equation*}
 (1-\al)p(x) + \al p(\x)j(x)=\phi(x), \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $j(x):=|\det{J_f(x)}|$ and $\x:=f(x)$. Replacing here $x$ by $\x$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 (1-\al)p(\x) + \al p(x)/j(x) =\phi(\x), \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
since $j(\x)=1/j(x)$. 
Solving the system of linear equations (1)--(2) for $p(x),p(\x)$, we find 
\begin{equation*}
 p(x)=\frac{(1-\al) \phi (x)-\al j(x) \phi (\x)}{2 \al-1}. 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. Can something be said when f is not an involution?

Comment: One way I can think of extending your approach is by assuming that $f^{-1}$ is contractive (which also means it has a fixed point). Then one can make use of the expressions for $\phi(x), \phi(f^{-1}(x)), \phi(f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(x)) \dots$ to at least approximately evaluate $p(x)$

Comment: More generally, if $f$ is not an involution, this suggests that the answer will depend on the structure of the orbits $\{x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots\}$. If the orbits are finite, then I think we can reason similarly.